A continuous rectifiable curve can be reparametrized by smooth curve?
If $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a continuous and rectifiable curve, then there exists a homeomorphism $\theta:[c,d]\to[a,b]$ such that the reparametrization $\gamma\circ\theta:[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuously differentiable?
For example the curve $\gamma(t)=(t,|t|)$, $t\in[-1,1]$ can be reparametrized by $\gamma(t)=(t^3,t^2|t|)$.
Any hints would be appreciated.

How does your trick work for the graph of a continuous but nowhere-differentiable function?

@TedShifrin However, graphs of nowhere-differentiable functions are not rectifiable, for a graph of a continuous function is rectifiable iff it has (locally) finite arc-length iff the function is (locally) of bounded variation, which implies that the function is almost everywhere differentiable. That being said, to take $\gamma$ to be the graph of Cantor's staircase function should be revealing.
